# Minimizing the probability on the partitions of a set

Tags: probability, probability-theory, optimization

Let $d,\ k<n$ be integers and $\Omega$ be a finite set. Let $E_1,\dots E_n$ be subsets of $\Omega$ such that
$$\forall \omega \in \Omega\qquad \sum_{i=1}^n \chi_{E_i}(\omega)=k.$$
(i.e. every point belongs to exactly $k$ sets of this family).
Is it true the following statement?

> The probability measure $\mu(\cdot)$ on $\Omega$ minimizing $$\mathbb P_{X_1,...X_d\overset{iid}\sim \mu}(\cup_{i=1}^n\cap_{j=1}^d X_j\in E_i)$$
> assigns the same probability to every set $E_i$.

Intuitively the question asks if, given i.i.d. random variables, the probability of having all them belonging to the same set is minimized when their distribution is uniform over the sets $E_i$.

**My considerations**

This result is indeed valid for $k=1$. This is because in this case the sets $E_i$ form a partition of $\Omega$, so that, calling $p_i$ the probability associated to each one, we have this optimization problem
$$\text{min}\sum_{i=1}^n p_i^d\qquad s.t. \qquad \sum_{i=1}^d p_i=1,$$
whose solution is of course $p_i=\frac{1}{n}$. Unfortunately, for hiher $k$ the definition of the optimization problem gets more difficult, and I cannot solve it trivially. I don't even known in WHICH FIELD of probability should this conjecture fall. Combinatorics? Optimization? Graph thoery? Elementary probability?